# C++ Reading from file incorrectly

Tags: c++, ifstream

There is a certain problem that I would like to have help with. Here is how it goes:

I'm using the following code to read a certain amount of characters into a char array to process later:

```
char str[15]; // first 16 characters that i need to get from file

  std::ifstream fin("example.txt");
  if(fin.is_open()){
      std::cout<<"File opened successfully \n";
         for(int i = 0;  i<=15; i++)
         {
            fin.get(str[i]); //reading one character from file to array

         }

  }
  else{
      std::cout<<"Failed to open file";
  }


  std::cout<<str;
```

It works fine for the first 4 or even 5 characters, but when it reaches to 8 it starts to print out garbage characters.

Contents of the example.txt file, from which i read text.

```
The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog
```

Output when I read 8 characters:

```
The Quic�j�
```

Output when I read 16 characters:

```
The Quick Brown ASCII
```

Why is this happening and where did the 'ASCII' come from when I try to read certain length from a file?

And lastly, what kind of code should I utilize if I want to get specific lengths from a file? For example if I want to read the first 4 or 8 or 16 or even 20 characters? It doesn't necessarily have to be into a char array, it can be saved into a string.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to put a `'\0'` character after the last one you read from the file.

Comment: std::string line; getline(fin, line); std::cout << line ; // The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog

Comment: Your char array needs to be larger or your loop needs to be < 15 and not <= 15.  C++ is a zero to n - 1 for array indices.

Comment: `read` reads blocks of bytes: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your char array is only 15 chars long. So this line goes out of bounds:

```
for(int i = 0;  i<=15; i++)
```

If `i` is equal to `15` that's one too many because your array counts from `0` to `14`.

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14` <= count them!

There are `15` places starting at `0` ending at `14`

Also when strings are stored in memory they have to be terminated by a null character `'\0'`. Otherwise the function that prints them doesn't know when to stop, which is probably where your garbage is coming from.

So, because the null terminator takes one of your `15` spaces, that only leaves you with 14 to read from the file.

So:

```
     for(int i = 0;  i < 14; i++)
     {
        fin.get(str[i]); //reading 14 characters (0-13)
     }
     str[14] = '\0'; // add the string terminator at the end of the array.
```

See if that works.

Comment: Oh yes! The null-terminator, how could i forget? I'm a bloody idiot. Thank you for the answer